# RuntimeWarning: unknown response content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' returning raw response

Tags: python-3.x, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to fetch details using the SPARQLWrapper and JSON format from the dbpedia database.

This is my code:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
sparql.setQuery("""
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?birth_date ?birth_place
WHERE {
?name rdfs:label "Ed Sheeran"@en .
?name dbo:birthDate ?birth_date .
?name dbo:birthPlace ?birth_place .
}"""
)

try:
    ret = sparql.queryAndConvert()
    ret = ret.decode('utf-8')
    # print(ret)
    # for r in ret["results"]["bindings"]:
    #     print(r)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get a giant result when I `print(ret)` but it doesn't print the result at all and gives the warning -

```
RuntimeWarning: unknown response content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' returning raw response...
  warnings.warn(
```

The query returns Ed Sheeran's birth date and birth place as expected in the JSON format when I try it in the official [SPARQL query for DBPedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql/).
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJqap.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIp27.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `http://dbpedia.org` is **not** the SPARQL endpoint but a simple web page which you can open in the browser. The endpoint URL is `https://dbpedia.org/sparql`

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks a lot! I had tried this endpoint on the web UI and it didn't work there, but the dbpedia webpage UI worked there so I thought it is only natural that it will be the same.

Comment: I don't get it, you tried which URL where exactly? I mean, if you open `http://dbpedia.org` in the browser, it's just a web page, isn't it? And if you open `https://dbpedia.org/sparql` you'll see a SPARQL query interface, right? If you mean the `http://dbpedia.org` inside this SPARQL query web interface, the label of the box indicates just the *"Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)"* as mentioned by the label above the textbox - this is the Graph URI you want to query, but not the SPARQL HTTP service which gives you access to this graph

Comment: I got confused between the usage of `http://dbpedia.org` and `https://dbpedia.org/sparql`. I get the difference now. Thanks a lot!